# Not all tables get created in SQLite database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have the following Problem:
Every time I want to access the table "Stores" in Logcat I can see this error message:

```
10-24 15:09:06.955: E/SQLiteLog(20264): (1) no such table: Stores
```

But when I delete the database, and create all the tables again, I don´t see any error while creating in Logcat. When I try to access or write into the table "Categories" I don´t have any error, only "Stores". When I later browse the SQLite Database in sqlitestudio, I only see the table categories with the values I insertet, nut no other, turns out also "OpeningHours" missing. Is it possible that I try to access these table while its not yet created?

Thats my code for creating:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(context.getString(R.string.sql_create));
}
```

and thats the SQL-Code

```
    <string name="sql_create">
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Categories` (

  `idCategories` INTEGER  NOT NULL ,

  `name` TEXT,

  PRIMARY KEY (`idCategories`) );


CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Stores` (

  `idStores` INTEGER NOT NULL ,

  `name` TEXT NOT NULL ,

  `locationAdress` TEXT  ,

  `locationLongitude` INTEGER ,

  `locationLatitude` INTEGER ,

  `category` INTEGER  NOT NULL ,

  `telephoneNumerber` TEXT  ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`idStores`) );


CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `OpeningHours` (

  `idOpeningHours` INTEGER  NOT NULL ,

  `store` INTEGER  NOT NULL ,

  `day` INTEGER ,

  `forenoon` TEXT  ,

  `afternoon` TEXT  ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`idOpeningHours`) );
    </string>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android `execSQL` executes a single statement: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)

Meaning you're only creating one table - `OpeningHours` - which is the last statement in your SQL script. You need to separate each create in one `execSQL` call.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use only one instance of SQLiteDatabase from all of your threads. This way you avoid many problems with accessing SQLite databases.